# Share models between Android client and Rails Backend (REST)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm creating an Android app that needs to make REST queries on an existing Rails app. The Rails app already has many models and the same models will probably be needed on Android (although I might be able to use simpler models).

What is the best way to be able to the model code between Rails and Android (possibly other logic too)? My google searching is coming up blank and the only other thing I can think of is to use some sort of WSDL (which would probably be overkill).